# Android проект выдаёт ошибку

Tags: android

Скажите как исправить ошибку?

```
package First.App2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;   

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Num1_btn);
    button.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
    );
```

Выдаёт ошибку на `OnClickListener` и `View v`

Comment: Чтобы знать как исправить ошибку в первую очередь нужно знать, какую именно ошибку.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.Num1_btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

и так: `import android.view.View;`

Comment: хорошо я всё понял